# What is a good introduction to integrable models in physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, integrable-systems

I would be interested in a good mathematician-friendly introduction to [integrable models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) in physics, either a book or expository article.

Related MathOverflow question: [what-is-an-integrable-system](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6379/what-is-an-integrable-system).

Comment: Do you have anything specific in mind? I think the term integrability is sometimes used in slightly different contexts.

Comment: The fact that "integrability" can mean so many things sometimes makes the quest to learn about it so challenging!  I have found the introductory sections of Etingoff's paper http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/zlecnew.pdf to be a very good mathematical reference for a particular, physically interesting system (Calogero-Moser) which describes particles interacting in one-dimension.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I take "integrable models" to mean "exactly solvable models in statistical physics".

You can take a look at the classic book

- [R. J. Baxter - Exactly Solved Models in Statistical mechanics](http://tpsrv.anu.edu.au/Members/baxter/book) (You can download it for free)

Otherwise this new book is quit readable and covers more than just solvable models

- [G. Mussardo - Statistical field theory: an introduction to exactly solved models in statistical physics](http://books.google.dk/books?id=JnLnXmBmCzsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Others can probably give you more mathematician-friendly references, but I think it would be good if you could be more specific about what you are looking for.

Comment: `Baxter` is a dead link.

Answer (score 3):

My references are very good reviews:

Quantum inverse scattering and Algebraic Bethe Ansatz:

Faddeev: How Algebraic Bethe Ansatz works for integrable model

Kulish and Sklyanin: Quantum Spectral Transform Method. Recent Developments

Takhtajan: Introduction to algebraic Bethe ansatz

and the Books:

Jimbo and Miwa: Algebraic Analysis of Solvable Lattice Models

Korepin et al: Quantum inverse Scattering and Correlation Functions

Korepin et al: The One-Dimensional Hubbard Model

plus the article

Martins and Ramos: The Quantum Inverse Scattering Method for Hubbard-like Models

Answer (score 1):

> This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. **Please note that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly discouraged by [the site's policy on resource recommendation questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)**. This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet have commentary.

- Another good recent book: Maciej Dunajski, [*Solitons, Instantons and Twistors*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Solitons_Instantons_and_Twistors.html?id=L8qUdjLxkuwC).
- Some very good reviews on Quantum inverse scattering and Algebraic Bethe Ansatz:

  - Faddeev: *How Algebraic Bethe Ansatz works for integrable model*
  - Kulish and Sklyanin: *Quantum Spectral Transform Method. Recent Developments*
  - Takhtajan: *Introduction to algebraic Bethe Ansatz*

  and the Books:

  - Jimbo and Miwa: *Algebraic Analysis of Solvable Lattice Models*
  - Korepin et al: *Quantum inverse Scattering and Correlation Functions*
  - Korepin et al: *The One-Dimensional Hubbard Model*

  plus the article

  - Martins and Ramos: The Quantum Inverse Scattering Method for Hubbard-like Models

Here are some more

- [*The Many-Body Problem: An Encyclopedia of Exactly Solved Models in One Dimension*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810209754)
- [*Beautiful Models: 70 Years of Exactly Solved Quantum Many-Body Problems*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9812388974)
- [*Exactly Solved Models: A Journey in Statistical Mechanics : Selected Papers with Commentaries*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9812813888)
- [*Introduction to Classical Integrable Systems*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052182267X)
- [*Classical Many-Body Problems Amenable to Exact Treatments*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540417648)
- [*Exact Methods in Low-dimensional Statistical Physics and Quantum Computing*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199574618)